# (Java) Error downloading File from Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I got these 3 errors on my code :

```
private static void downloadFile(Drive service, String fileId) {
    try {

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.csv");
        service.files().export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // An error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here's the error results :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   googleBaru.mainClass.downloadFile(mainClass.java:51) at
>   googleBaru.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:60)

I hope anyone can fix my code, or how am I suppose to do to calling the method (with parameter service and fileId)

many thanks, sorry for my bad English

Comment: Assuming your `Drive` object exists, was initialized properly, etc., another problem is that you are trying to open an output stream at a relative location `test.csv`, which might not make sense.  Try using a full path instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

> I got these 3 errors on my code.

Actually, this is a stacktrace ... and it describes ONE error, not three.

The error is on line 51 of your `mainclass.java` file.  That will be this one:

```
  service.files().export(fileId, 
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").
      executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Assuming that `service` is supposed to be a `Drive` object, then looking at this from a Java perspective:

- the `service` reference could be null,
- the `files()` method could have returned `null` (impossible I think), or
- the `export()` method could have returned `null` (impossible I think).

The "impossible" cases according to my reading of the Drive API javadocs.

In short, the most plausible explanation is that your `service` reference is `null`.  Find out why, and fix the cause.

---

@TimBiegeleisen's comment about the file path may also be correct, but that won't be the cause of the `NullPointerException` you are seeing.